# AWS ECS using Nginx instead ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I trying to set up a stack on AWS ECS.
In a regular case, I can use ALB and configure many listeners for many backends. But I have a case where I have many SSL certifications that have to be terminated. AWS ALB has a limit for the number of certificates that is far way below my needs.

I'm thinking to use Nginx instead of ALB and route requests for the services.
To do that I create a fargate deployment type EC2 with the Nginx. On Nginx prepare config to services using AWS Cloud Map. To Nginx I'll add all necessary certificates.

If my solution make sense? If not, maybe any suggestions on how to do it better?

Answer (score 1):

> To do that I create a fargate deployment type EC2 with the Nginx.

This statement can't be correct. You either deploy to Fargate, or you deploy to EC2. Those are the two deployment targets for ECS. They are mutually exclusive. You either use one or the other.

> To do that I create a fargate deployment type EC2 with the Nginx. On Nginx prepare config to services using AWS Cloud Map. To Nginx I'll add all necessary certificates. If my solution make sense?

This solution only makes sense if all the things that need to access your services are also running inside the same VPC. AWS Cloud Map only updates a Route53 private hosted zone that is connected to your VPC. This means only other things in the same VPC can resolve the DNS names that are managed by Cloud Map.

I believe a more appropriate solution is to switch to a Network Load Balancer, configured in TCP Passthrough mode, pointing at your Nginx ECS deployment. You would then still terminate all the SSL certificates in Nginx.